# Why the idle task of linux(Swapper) running with preempt disabled?

Tags: linux, multithreading, schedule, ftrace

Two evidence reveal that the linux swapper task(idle) running with the premeditation disabled:

1: the preempt count object initialized with INIT_PREEMPT_COUNT, which value is "1",means disable the preempt.

```
#define INIT_THREAD_INFO(tsk)                       \
{                                   \
   .task       = &tsk,                     \
   .flags      = 0,                        \
   .preempt_count  = INIT_PREEMPT_COUNT,               \
   .addr_limit = KERNEL_DS,                    \
}
```

2.from the ftrace of irqsoff, preempt-depth set to 1, which means preemption disabled.

```
# tracer: irqsoff
#
# irqsoff latency trace v1.1.5 on 4.15.10+
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# latency: 3464 us, #4/4, CPU#2 | (M:preempt VP:0, KP:0, SP:0 HP:0 #P:4)
#    -----------------
#    | task: swapper/2-0 (uid:0 nice:0 policy:0 rt_prio:0)
#    -----------------
#  => started at: rcu_idle_exit
#  => ended at:   rcu_idle_exit
#
#
#                  _------=> CPU#            
#                 / _-----=> irqs-off        
#                | / _----=> need-resched    
#                || / _---=> hardirq/softirq 
#                ||| / _--=> preempt-depth   
#                |||| /     delay            
#  cmd     pid   ||||| time  |   caller      
#     \   /      |||||  \    |   /         
  <idle>-0       2dn.1  927us#: rcu_idle_exit
  <idle>-0       2dn.1 3067us!: rcu_idle_exit
  <idle>-0       2dn.1 3645us#: trace_hardirqs_on <-rcu_idle_exit
  <idle>-0       2dn.1 5713us : <stack trace>
```

so , Why design like this?

Answer (score 0):

you can trace cpu_idle_loop this function

what the function do is check if we need to give the cpu up and rescheduling(context switch)

and the action just like preemption